# How to automatically use appropriate precision/scale for numeric type in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `numeric` type in postgres with a value of `1.9999999999999999` (scale is 16) and I run a query that calculates `(1.9999999999999999+2)/2`. The exact answer should be `1.99999999999999995` (scale should be 17) but instead I get `2.0000000000000000` (scale is still 16 again) because the default precision/scale of `numeric` is exceeded.

I could get around this by running the query and doing `(1.9999999999999999+2)/2::numeric(1000,999)`, but then when I retrieve this value that was saved to the database, it actually appears with 1000 "0" digits in the SELECT query output.

How can I do either of the following?

- Tell postgres never to round a value if it exceeds the scale, but increase the scale automatically instead
- Tell postgres not to store trailing "0" digits after the decimal, and keep only the minimum number of digits it needs, so that I can use the highest possible scale `::numeric(1000,999)` but it only stores the necessary digits?

I'd like to get exact results for any operations I do on numeric values to the fullest precision that postgres allows, but not store unnecessary trailing "0" digits. Like how you would expect it to work if you were calculating it manually.